# How do I add a region to the Color module?

Tags: theming, 8

I have a menu I would like to be able to style with the Color module.  I have found many examples for the Drupal 7 Color module and they have led me to believe that if I just add a line to the 'fields' array in the color.inc file in my theme I will be able to add more regions.

Below is my 'fields' array.  I copied an existing file as a guide and simply added my primary menu

```
'fields' => array(
  'top' => t('Header background top'),
  'bottom' => t('Header background bottom'),
  'primarymenu' => t('Primary navigation menu'),
  'bg' => t('Main background'),
  'sidebar' => t('Sidebar background'),
  'sidebarborders' => t('Sidebar borders'),
  'footer' => t('Footer background'),
  'titleslogan' => t('Title and slogan'),
  'text' => t('Text color'),
  'link' => t('Link color'),
),
```

I just added the 'primarymenu' field to the standard bartik array

I realize there is more to do to connect this field to something so it will actually change colors but everything I can find is for D7 and requires altering php templates.

Why is my field not showing up in the appearance settings menu and how do I connect it to change the color of my menu?

Edited To add the schemes array

```
'schemes' => array(
'default' => array(
  'title' => t('Blue Lagoon (default)'),
  'colors' => array(
    'top' => '#055a8e',
    'bottom' => '#1d84c3',
            'primarymenu' => '#ffffff',
    'bg' => '#ffffff',
    'sidebar' => '#f6f6f2',
    'sidebarborders' => '#f9f9f9',
    'footer' => '#292929',
    'titleslogan' => '#fffeff',
    'text' => '#3b3b3b',
    'link' => '#0071B3',
  ),
),
'firehouse' => array(
  'title' => t('Firehouse'),
  'colors' => array(
    'top' => '#cd2d2d',
    'bottom' => '#d64e4e',
            'primarymenu' => '#ffffff',
    'bg' => '#ffffff',
    'sidebar' => '#f1f4f0',
    'sidebarborders' => '#ededed',
    'footer' => '#1f1d1c',
    'titleslogan' => '#fffeff',
    'text' => '#888888',
    'link' => '#d6121f',
  ),
),
'ice' => array(
  'title' => t('Ice'),
  'colors' => array(
    'top' => '#d0d0d0',
    'bottom' => '#c2c4c5',
            'primarymenu' => '#ffffff',
    'bg' => '#ffffff',
    'sidebar' => '#ffffff',
    'sidebarborders' => '#cccccc',
    'footer' => '#016b83',
    'titleslogan' => '#000000',
    'text' => '#4a4a4a',
    'link' => '#019dbf',
  ),
),
'plum' => array(
  'title' => t('Plum'),
  'colors' => array(
    'top' => '#4c1c58',
    'bottom' => '#593662',
            'primarymenu' => '#ffffff',
    'bg' => '#fffdf7',
    'sidebar' => '#edede7',
    'sidebarborders' => '#e7e7e7',
    'footer' => '#2c2c28',
    'titleslogan' => '#ffffff',
    'text' => '#301313',
    'link' => '#9d408d',
  ),
),
'slate' => array(
  'title' => t('Slate'),
  'colors' => array(
    'top' => '#4a4a4a',
    'bottom' => '#4e4e4e',
            'primarymenu' => '#ffffff',
    'bg' => '#ffffff',
    'sidebar' => '#ffffff',
    'sidebarborders' => '#d0d0d0',
    'footer' => '#161617',
    'titleslogan' => '#ffffff',
    'text' => '#3b3b3b',
    'link' => '#0073b6',
  ),
),
```

),

Answer (score 0):

You need to also provide a color for the field you added. In fact, the function that adds the form elements for the color settings contains the following code. (See [`color_scheme_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!color!color.module/function/color_scheme_form/8).)

```
 foreach ($palette as $name => $value) {
    if (isset($names[$name])) {
      $form['palette'][$name] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => $names[$name],
        '#value_callback' => 'color_palette_color_value',
        '#default_value' => $value,
        '#size' => 8,
        '#attributes' => array('dir' => LanguageInterface::DIRECTION_LTR),
      );
    }
  }
```

Without a color value for your field, `$form['palette'][$name]` will not be added, and it will not be possible to change the color for it.

In fact, the Bartik theme uses the following values, for its default palette.

```
$info['schemes']['default'] = array(
  'title' => t('Blue Lagoon (default)'),
  'colors' => array(
    'top' => '#055a8e',
    'bottom' => '#1d84c3',
    'bg' => '#ffffff',
    'sidebar' => '#f6f6f2',
    'sidebarborders' => '#f9f9f9',
    'footer' => '#292929',
    'titleslogan' => '#fffeff',
    'text' => '#3b3b3b',
    'link' => '#0071B3',
  ),
);
```

The keys you find in (for example) `$info['schemes']['default']['colors']` are the same keys you find in `$info['fields']`.

Comment: I added my schemes array as well and pasted the code above, however it still does not show up on my page

Comment: Which code above?

Comment: I pasted my schemes array as an edit to the original question

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and after a lot of face-palming, I discovered why the new color field was not showing up.

In my case, I had already saved custom color settings for the original fields before adding my new field. Since the custom settings obviously didn't contain a value for my new field, it was excluded from display in the theme settings. Using the drop-down menu to change back to the default (or some other preset) color scheme solved the issue and then I was able to pick custom colors including the new field.